# Question Concerning a Lamp Switch

Tags: diodes, switches, mains

I have a question regarding an overheating lamp switch I just fixed in my living room. Below is a diagram of what it looked like internally. It's not exactly a push switch, but a rotating wheel which is half dielectric, half conductive. Anyways, what is the purpose of the diode connected between the main facing terminal and the piece which the connects the two terminals? It seems superfluous. Why not just have the two terminals and the portion that connects them when turned on?[image]

Comment: Is this a dimming lamp?  Photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIRkUD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The two-stage lamp switch works as a crude dimmer.*

Without more details I'd guess that the switch has a two-stage cam working on three positions of the switch: off - dim - full. The diode forms a crude half-wave rectifier to dim the lamp.

There are two problems with this:

1. It may cause lamp flicker.
2. It's drawing DC from the supply transformer which is generally a bad idea as it tends to move the operating point off-centre in the magnetic circuit.

Comment: Yes it does have 3 positions. Thank you for the reply - it makes sense now.